# QPushButton with an alpha level of 0% turns solid when moused over. How to fix Qt with C++ (with stylesheets?)

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qpushbutton

I have designed two different kinds of QPushButtons in Qt Designer. One is the default, the other I want to be clear.
In QT Designer I set the latter's initial style sheet like such:

```
background-color: rgba( 35, 35, 35, 0% );
```

I want the button to have a border and to be clear (the internal color isn't really important; that just happens to match the color scheme). When I mouse over the button I want it to REMAIN clear, however instead it turns to the solid grey that is 35/35/35.

When the button receives a signal press I want it to turn a half transparent green:

```
    background-color: rgba( 0, 255, 0, 50% );
```

Before I realized the mouse-over would be a problem, I had this coded:

```
QString MyPanel::FillInvisibleButton(bool activeButton)
{
  QString invisibleButton;

  if (activeButton) {
     invisibleButton = "QPushButton{background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 50%);}";
  } else {
     invisibleButton = "QPushButton{background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0%);}";
  }
  return invisibleButton;
}


//Signals
void MyPanel::MyButtonPressed()
{
   m_ui->myButton->setStyleSheet(FillInvisibleButton(true));
}

void MyPanel::MyButtonReleased()
{
   m_ui->myButton->setStyleSheet(FillInvisibleButton(false));
}
```

That works great as far as making the clear button a transparent green when it's pressed... but it has the big grey opaque block on it when it's moused over which I want to go away!

I've tried this:

```
    QString MyPanel::FillInvisibleButton(bool activeButton)
{
  QString invisibleButton;

  if (activeButton) {
     invisibleButton = "QPushButton{background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 50%);} QPushButton:hover{background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0%);}";
  } else {
     invisibleButton = "QPushButton{background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0%);} QPushButton:hover{background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0%);}";
  }
  return invisibleButton;
}
```

And it doesn't work at all. They still mouse-over grey and now they don't turn green at all.

Is my syntax just wrong? Or?? I'm new to Qt and very rusty on C++.
I'm not married to the Stylesheets. If there's a better way to accomplish it that's great. Just keep in mind that I can't do this to ALL of my buttons; just several of them.

Thanks!

ETA: I believe I'm using 4.5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use signals, stylesheet is enough.
Try this one:

```
QPushButton {
    background-color: rgba( 35, 35, 35, 0% );
    border: 1px solid black;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba( 0, 255, 0, 50% );
}
```

Comment: But where do I put that? It's gotta be in the cpp file because I can't touch the file that Qt designer generates. It's part of an automated build process.

Comment: In Qt Designer: right click on the widget, "Change styleSheet...", paste this text.

Comment: Oh man I feel stupid. I didn't know you could put that much detail in the button style sheets themselves. You're right... I can totally ditch all my complicated signal button changing stuff. Fantastic!

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/stylesheet-reference.html - here is described how you can customize the look of different widgets.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet you can use 'hover' pseudo state:

```
button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover { ... }");
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused how that's different than what I had?